# I have a bar chart with error bars in matplotlib (python), but i want the error bars in the middle of the bar. how do i do this? Thanks

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

```
#Figure 1, right at the bottom of the code, needs the error bars.

import scipy as sp

import numpy as np

import pylab as pl

import matplotlib as mpl

import numpy.random as nr

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

M = 91.0

G = 2.5

RS = 0.14

JS = -0.033

S = np.arange(20,140,0.1)

def sigs(com):

    for i in com:

        yield  ((4.0*np.pi)/3.0)*((1/i**2) + (((i**2)*RS + JS*((i**2)-M**2))/(((i**2)-M**2)**2 + (M*G)**2)))


x = list(sigs(S))


RA = 0.0027

JA = 0.81

def siga(com):

    for i in com:

        yield np.pi*((i**2)*RA + JA*((i**2) - M**2))/((((i**2) - M**2)**2) + (M*G)**2) 


a = list(siga(S))


N = []

for m in x:

    N.append(1000000*8*m/3)


cos = np.arange(-0.95, 0.90, 0.05)

sin = np.arange(-0.90, 0.95, 0.05) 

M = []

for (i, j) in zip(cos,sin):

    M.append((1000000*j*(0.094 + 0.0313*j*j + 0.000679*j))-(1000000*i*(0.094 + 0.0313*i*i + 0.000679*i)))


s = np.random.poisson(M)

z = []

for t in s:

    z.append(t**0.5)

plt.figure(4)

pl.bar(cos, s, width = 0.05)

pl.xlabel('cos${\Theta}$')

pl.ylabel('Number of muons produced within the cos${\Theta}$ interval')
yerr = z

plt.errorbar(cos, s, yerr=yerr, fmt = 'o')

pl.show()
```

Answer (score 4):

Note that [`bar()` also accepts a `yerr=` argument](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html?highlight=bar#matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar):

```
pl.bar(cos, s, width=0.05, yerr=yerr)
```

This will automatically place the errorbars in the centers of each bar. There's no need to draw the bars first, then use `errorbar()` to draw errorbars on top.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use the same x-data (cos in your case) for the error bars and bar plot. One simple solution is to add 1/2 bar width to the x-data for the error bars, in other words:

```
plt.errorbar(cos + 0.025 , s, yerr=yerr, fmt = 'o')
```

where 0.025 is half the bar width.